# Cannot run Opengl program

Tags: c++, opengl, runtime-error

I took this progrAM from OpenGL superbible 5th edition.I setup everything like they said in the book,the include paths and also including existing items for the project.

Then I created a new c++ file in the project and copy paste code I downloaded from the official site.

```
    // Block.cpp
        // OpenGL SuperBible, Chapter 1
        // Demonstrates an assortment of basic 3D concepts
        // Program by Richard S. Wright Jr.

#include <GLTools.h>    // OpenGL toolkit
#include <GLMatrixStack.h>
#include <GLFrame.h>
#include <GLFrustum.h>
#include <GLBatch.h>
#include <GLGeometryTransform.h>

#include <math.h>
#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h>
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h>
#endif

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// An assortment of needed classes
GLShaderManager     shaderManager;
GLMatrixStack       modelViewMatrix;
GLMatrixStack       projectionMatrix;
GLFrame             cameraFrame;
GLFrustum           viewFrustum;
GLBatch             cubeBatch;
GLBatch             floorBatch;
GLBatch             topBlock;
GLBatch             frontBlock;
GLBatch             leftBlock;

GLGeometryTransform transformPipeline;
M3DMatrix44f        shadowMatrix;


// Keep track of effects step
int nStep = 0;

// Lighting data
GLfloat lightAmbient[] = { 0.2f, 0.2f, 0.2f, 1.0f };
GLfloat lightDiffuse[] = { 0.7f, 0.7f, 0.7f, 1.0f };
GLfloat lightSpecular[] = { 0.9f, 0.9f, 0.9f };
GLfloat vLightPos[] = { -8.0f, 20.0f, 100.0f, 1.0f };

GLuint textures[4];


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Make a cube out of a batch of triangles. Texture coordinates and normals
// are also provided.
void MakeCube(GLBatch& cubeBatch)
    {
    cubeBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 36, 1);

    /////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Top of cube
    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);


    ////////////////////////////////////////////
    // Bottom of cube
    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    ///////////////////////////////////////////
    // Left side of cube
    cubeBatch.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Right side of cube
    cubeBatch.Normal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    // Front and Back
    // Front
    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

    // Back
    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f);
    cubeBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    cubeBatch.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

    cubeBatch.End();
    }

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Make the floor, just the verts and texture coordinates, no normals
void MakeFloor(GLBatch& floorBatch)
    {
    GLfloat x = 5.0f;
    GLfloat y = -1.0f;

    floorBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, 1);
        floorBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        floorBatch.Vertex3f(-x, y, x);

        floorBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        floorBatch.Vertex3f(x, y, x);

        floorBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        floorBatch.Vertex3f(x, y, -x);

        floorBatch.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        floorBatch.Vertex3f(-x, y, -x);
    floorBatch.End();
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering context. 
// This is the first opportunity to do any OpenGL related tasks.
void SetupRC()
    {
    GLbyte *pBytes;
    GLint nWidth, nHeight, nComponents;
    GLenum format;

    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

    // Black background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    glLineWidth(2.5f);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    transformPipeline.SetMatrixStacks(modelViewMatrix, projectionMatrix);

    cameraFrame.MoveForward(-15.0f);
    cameraFrame.MoveUp(6.0f);
    cameraFrame.RotateLocalX(float(m3dDegToRad(20.0f)));

    MakeCube(cubeBatch);
    MakeFloor(floorBatch);

    // Make top
    topBlock.Begin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, 1);
        topBlock.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        topBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        topBlock.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        topBlock.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        topBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        topBlock.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        topBlock.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        topBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        topBlock.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);

        topBlock.Normal3f(0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        topBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        topBlock.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    topBlock.End();

    // Make Front
    frontBlock.Begin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, 1);
        frontBlock.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        frontBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        frontBlock.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        frontBlock.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        frontBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        frontBlock.Vertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        frontBlock.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        frontBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        frontBlock.Vertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        frontBlock.Normal3f(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        frontBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        frontBlock.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    frontBlock.End();

    // Make left
    leftBlock.Begin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 4, 1);
        leftBlock.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        leftBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        leftBlock.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);

        leftBlock.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        leftBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 0.0f);
        leftBlock.Vertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);

        leftBlock.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        leftBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        leftBlock.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);

        leftBlock.Normal3f(-1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
        leftBlock.MultiTexCoord2f(0, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        leftBlock.Vertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    leftBlock.End();

    // Create shadow projection matrix
    GLfloat floorPlane[] = { 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    m3dMakePlanarShadowMatrix(shadowMatrix, floorPlane, vLightPos);

    // Load up four textures  
    glGenTextures(4, textures);

    // Wood floor
    pBytes = gltReadTGABits("floor.tga", &nWidth, &nHeight, &nComponents, &format);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,nComponents,nWidth, nHeight, 0,
        format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
    free(pBytes);

    // One of the block faces
    pBytes = gltReadTGABits("Block4.tga", &nWidth, &nHeight, &nComponents, &format);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,nComponents,nWidth, nHeight, 0,
        format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
    free(pBytes);

    // Another block face
    pBytes = gltReadTGABits("block5.tga", &nWidth, &nHeight, &nComponents, &format);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[2]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,nComponents,nWidth, nHeight, 0,
        format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
    free(pBytes);

    // Yet another block face
    pBytes = gltReadTGABits("block6.tga", &nWidth, &nHeight, &nComponents, &format);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[3]);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D,0,nComponents,nWidth, nHeight, 0,
        format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, pBytes);
    free(pBytes);
    }




///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Render the block
void RenderBlock(void)
    {
    GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
    GLfloat vWhite[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f };

    switch(nStep)
        {
        // Wire frame
        case 0:
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vRed);
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
            glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);

            // Draw the cube
            cubeBatch.Draw();

            break;

        // Wire frame, but not the back side... we also want the block to be in the stencil buffer
        case 1:
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vRed);

            // Draw solid block in stencil buffer
            // Back face culling prevents the back sides from showing through
            // The stencil pattern is used to mask when we draw the floor under it
            // to keep it from showing through.
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
            glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
            glStencilFunc(GL_NEVER, 0, 0);
            glStencilOp(GL_INCR, GL_INCR, GL_INCR);
            cubeBatch.Draw();
            glStencilOp(GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP, GL_KEEP);
            glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);

            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);

            // Draw the front side cube
            cubeBatch.Draw();
            break;

        // Solid
        case 2:
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vRed);

            // Draw the cube
            cubeBatch.Draw();
            break;

        // Lit
        case 3:
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_POINT_LIGHT_DIFF, modelViewMatrix.GetMatrix(),
                projectionMatrix.GetMatrix(), vLightPos, vRed);

            // Draw the cube
            cubeBatch.Draw();
            break;

        // Textured & Lit
        case 4:
        case 5:
        default:
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[2]);
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_TEXTURE_POINT_LIGHT_DIFF, modelViewMatrix.GetMatrix(),
                projectionMatrix.GetMatrix(), vLightPos, vWhite, 0);

            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[1]);
            topBlock.Draw();
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[2]);
            frontBlock.Draw();
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[3]);
            leftBlock.Draw();

            break;
        }

    // Put everything back
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Render the floor
void RenderFloor(void)
    {
    GLfloat vBrown [] = { 0.55f, 0.292f, 0.09f, 1.0f};
    GLfloat vFloor[] = { 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.6f };

    switch(nStep)
        {
        // Wire frame
        case 0:
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vBrown);
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
            glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
            break;

        // Wire frame, but not the back side.. and only where stencil == 0
        case 1:
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glEnable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);

            glEnable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
            glStencilFunc(GL_EQUAL, 0, 0xff);

            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vBrown);
            glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_LINE);
            break;

        // Solid
        case 2:
        case 3: 
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_FLAT, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vBrown);
            break;

        // Textured
        case 4:
        case 5:
        default:
            glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
            shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_TEXTURE_MODULATE, transformPipeline.GetModelViewProjectionMatrix(), vFloor, 0);
            break;
        }

    // Draw the floor
    floorBatch.Draw();

    // Put everything back
    glPolygonMode(GL_FRONT_AND_BACK, GL_FILL);
    glEnable(GL_CULL_FACE);
    glDisable(GL_BLEND);
    glDisable(GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glDisable(GL_STENCIL_TEST);
    }



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
    {
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();
        M3DMatrix44f mCamera;
        cameraFrame.GetCameraMatrix(mCamera);
        modelViewMatrix.MultMatrix(mCamera);

        // Reflection step... draw cube upside down, the floor
        // blended on top of it
        if(nStep == 5) {
            glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
            modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();
            modelViewMatrix.Scale(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
            modelViewMatrix.Translate(0.0f, 2.0f, 0.0f);
            modelViewMatrix.Rotate(35.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            RenderBlock();
            modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();
            glEnable(GL_BLEND);
            glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
            RenderFloor();
            glDisable(GL_BLEND);            
            }


        modelViewMatrix.PushMatrix();

            // Draw normally
            modelViewMatrix.Rotate(35.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
            RenderBlock();
        modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();


    // If not the reflection pass, draw floor last
    if(nStep != 5)
        RenderFloor();


    modelViewMatrix.PopMatrix();


    // Flush drawing commands
    glutSwapBuffers();
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// A normal ASCII key has been pressed.
// In this case, advance the scene when the space bar is pressed
void KeyPressFunc(unsigned char key, int x, int y)
    {
    if(key == 32)
        {
        nStep++;

        if(nStep > 5)
            nStep = 0;
        }

    // Refresh the Window
    glutPostRedisplay();
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Window has changed size, or has just been created. In either case, we need
// to use the window dimensions to set the viewport and the projection matrix.
void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
    {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    viewFrustum.SetPerspective(35.0f, float(w) / float(h), 1.0f, 500.0f);
    projectionMatrix.LoadMatrix(viewFrustum.GetProjectionMatrix());
    modelViewMatrix.LoadIdentity();
    }

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main entry point for GLUT based programs
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("3D Effects Demo");

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err)
        {
        /* Problem: glewInit failed, something is seriously wrong. */
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
        }

    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(KeyPressFunc);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

    SetupRC();

    glutMainLoop();
    glDeleteTextures(4,textures);
    return 0;
    }
```

I debug the program(I use visual C++ 2008,and i get the following error:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: meow, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>..\..\..\..\..\SB5\VisualStudio2008\GLTools\gltools.lib : fatal error LNK1107: invalid or corrupt file: cannot read at 0x13B5
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\sripriya\Downloads\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\meow\meow\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>meow - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't understand since I linked the gltools well and it appears in the sub list under the projects name.Why is this happening?

EDIT: Now when I run I get this

```
1>------ Build started: Project: meow, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Linking...
1>LINK : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup
1>C:\Users\sripriya\Downloads\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\meow\Debug\meow.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\sripriya\Downloads\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\meow\meow\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>meow - 2 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I've got no clue!

NOTE:GlTools is added as a vc++ project not a library,should i add extension.lib?I tried still got the same error,unresolved I dont know what....

```
1>------ Build started: Project: meow2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>gt.cpp
1>c:\users\sripriya\downloads\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\meow2\meow2\gt.cpp(6) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLTools.h': No such file or directory
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\sripriya\Downloads\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\meow2\meow2\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>meow2 - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to need to right click your project from the solution explorer -> Properties -> Linker -> System and make sure that SubSystem is set to Console.

Comment: It now says:1>------ Build started: Project: meow2, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>Compiling...
1>gt.cpp
1>c:\users\sripriya\downloads\documents\visual studio 2008\projects\meow2\meow2\gt.cpp(6) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'GLTools.h': No such file or directory
1>Build log was saved at "file://c:\Users\sripriya\Downloads\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\Projects\meow2\meow2\Debug\BuildLog.htm"
1>meow2 - 1 error(s), 0 warning(s)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========

Comment: @SripriyaSridharan This sounds like a totally different issues for a different question. But I believe that this is caused by your `include directory` not set right. Make sure that where ever `GLTools.h` is on your computer is in your `include directory`

Comment: I just checked it and it is.

Comment: Right click on #include "GLTools.h" and select Open Document. If it not opens - include directory not set right. (go to "Project properties -> Configuration properties -> С.С++ -> General -> Addition include directories. And add GLTools folder path.

Comment: @The program got compiled! I have a set of warnings but it succeeded so thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

> > unresolved external symbol _mainCRTStartup

Linker can't find program entry point.

You can set up it manually (go to "Project properties -> Configuration properties -> Linker -> Command Line) and add at additional options field "/entry:mainCRTStartup"

If this doesn't help try to switch subsystem flag (Project properties -> Configuration properties -> Linker -> System) between SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS and SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE.

Comment: It still doesnt work,I get the last error message i have updated.I rally dont know whats going on.

Answer (score 0):

The unresolved externals means somthings not linked right, im pretty sure.